# FileNotFoundException when using BufferedReader on a file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, ioexception, filenotfoundexception

I'm very confused on getting basic file reading to work with Java.  Lots of mixed signals.

I've tried it a couple different ways and I consistently get a not found exception each time.  I've checked with a file object set to the current path to print the current directory and I am indeed in the directory the file I'm trying to open is in.  The permissions are set so everyone can read.  I'm not sure what is going on:

```
BufferedReader infixLines = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( "input.infix" ));
```

This is the line that throws the error, consequently each consecutive line using infixLines also throws an error.

I've tried it using FileInputStream as well and get the same kind of error.

That being said simply doing

```
File file = new File("input.infix");
if ( file.exists() )
    System.out.println( "Exists" );
```

DOES work.

Very confused.

EDIT: (Stacktrace?)

```
ParseInfix.java:13: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be
            BufferedReader infixLines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (n
                                                           ^
ParseInfix.java:15: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or
            while ( ( line = infixLines.readLine()) != null )
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to the question? Have you tried creating it like so: `new FileReader(new File("input.infix"));`

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Are you *certain* that the permissions are set so that you can read the file? Can you load the file in a text editor outside your program?

Comment: Running on a remote linux server I'm sshed into.  Loads up into vim like a dream.  I am quite certain the permissions are read for everyone.

Comment: Are you perhaps running SELinux? There's a whole new world of permissions in there if you are.

Comment: No; that being said, I'm pretty sure it's not a permissions issue--haven't had any permissions issues reading text files in any other language.  I'm a Java nub and very impatient with the language and this is killing me.  On the Java nub topic, how would I go about getting the stack trace?  I edited in what I think you're looking for David, let me know.  Like I said, java nub here.

Comment: I can open and manipulate the file fine in Python.

Comment: Check the file is readable or not, with `file.canRead()`.

Comment: file.canRead() returns true on a file object that opens said file.

Comment: The "stack trace" above looks a lot like compiler error messages, not like a stack trace. Are you sure you are asking the right question?

Comment: As an FYI - the lines of code you are describing are not throwing an error.  "Throwing an error" is a runtime idea that means that the code compiles and runs, but fails at runtime.  Your error is that your program isn't legal Java.  As a general rule, try to differentiate between compile-time errors (the program won't compile and run at all) and runtime errors (it compiles, but doesn't do the right thing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception trace is saying that your code...

```
BufferedReader infixLines = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( "input.infix" ));
```

Could *possibly* throw a `FileNotFoundException` or an `IOException` if the file doesn't exist, so it wants you to do something to handle this possibility.

The simplest way is to wrap your file-reading code in a `try-catch` block like this...

```
try {
    BufferedReader infixLines = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( "input.infix" ));
    // other reading code here
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The exception isn't saying that the file can't be found, it is just saying that *if* the file doesn't exist, what is your code going to do to handle the situation.

Ultimately in the `catch` block you would want to do something more than just `System.out.println()`. For example, in a GUI program, you might show a popup message to tell the user that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: If he is using Java 7, he can pipe the exceptions as well: `catch(FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {`

Comment: I wrapped it as you suggested and when I go to actually use my BufferedReader object later (after the try catches) it can't find the symbol.  Suggesting to me that it simply failed in the try block, of course nothing was printed to console either.  Just more errors.  I tried declaring infixLines outside of the try statement and then set it inside the try statement and this just confused the situation.

Comment: You need **all** your file-reading code to be in the `try` section, so that it only does all the file read access *if* the file could be opened by the `BufferedReader`. Basically everything that tries to access `infixLines` will need to be in the `try` section.

Comment: Well, that does it then!  Thanks, I'm certainly not a fan of this method.  Is there a less intrusive method for the coder so that you don't have to wrap it all in exception handling?  I've never encountered such a moody way of file I/O.  I generally accept that it's not all sunshine and daisies, but this is a bit absurd from my dominantly Python/C/C++ background.  Hell, even C# isn't this verbose for file I/O.

Comment: Exception handling is very important - you really need to ensure you correctly handle a situation that could create an exception. Without exception handling, your program will be left in an undefined state, and won't know how to behave. Exception handling tries to predict the possible problems that could occur, and allows you to handle them nicely so that the program doesn't simply crash.

Comment: I'm a large fan of exception handling, yet it's been impressed upon me that exception handling should be for exceptional situations.  File I/O is hardly exceptional, a pretty common task.  Again, most other languages don't require you to encapsulate these in try catches to compile.  Yes, you'll probably want to be able to catch invalid files, but for a very lightweight program that you're going to throw away probably.  Well, at that point, I guess Java isn't really the tool of choice.  Like I said in another comment, I'm just wayyyy impatient with Java.

Thanks very much for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
BufferedReader infixLines = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("input.infix"));
```

searches for File: `input.infix`, if it not found then it will return `FileNotFoundException` exception. Make sure that `input.infix` resides in the directory same with the `java file`.

Answer (score 1):

Its a **compilation error**, not a runtime exception.

You need to wrap your File related calls within a try-catch block and handle `FileNotFounceException` and `IOException`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String fileName = "input.infix";
File fil = new File(fileName);
String filePath = fil.getAbsolutePath();
BufferedReader infixLines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
```